# how is this function passing considered as separator and arguments

Tags: javascript

Learning Javascript functions from here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

I couldn't get this concept- How was comma assigned to separator ?

```
 function myConcat(separator) {

   console.log(separator); // ,  -> how was this interpreted as comma?
   console.log(arguments.length); // 4
   var result = ''; // initialize list
   var i;
   // iterate through arguments
   for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      result += arguments[i] + separator;
   }
   return result;
}

myConcat(', ', 'red', 'orange', 'blue');
```

### Output:

```
, 
4
red, orange, blue,
```

Comment: It *is* the first (and only named) argument. Change it to something else and you'll see it is not THE separator for the other arguments, as you seem to think.

Comment: I think its a mistake to learn the `arguments` object at all. Just ignore it, you wont miss it...

Comment: Try `myConcat('_X_', 'red', 'orange', 'blue');` and the comma will be gone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets imagine `arguments` does not exist. Then one would write the function like this:

```
function myConcat(separator, ...array) {
  var result = ""; // initialize the resulting string
  // iterate over the array
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result += array[i] + separator;
   }
   return result;
}
```

So now its clear that the myConcat function has a parameter called `seperator` followed by a so called `rest parameter` array. That means that whenever you call the function, the first argument is passed to seperator and all the following arguments are collected in the `array` array.

```
 myConcat(/*seperator*/ "a",/*...array*/ "b", "n", "n", "!");
```

---

As you are coming from a java background, the same written in java would be:

```
class Helpers {
  static String myConcat(String seperator, String[] ...array){
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      result += array[i] + seperator;
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much for details, I understood why i was getting that o/p . However comparing to Java, In Java we clearly mention that my first parameter is String, and second parameter is Array. But here , all the parameters are String , which we have to interpret as a String param followed by String array ( by looking at function declaration) although we haven't explicitly declaring an array using  `[]` or `new Array[]`.

Comment: @spiderman the spread property is automatically an array of values ( arrays are typeless and can therefore have mixed types) and `arguments` is automatically an *arraylike object*. You could also do `myConcat(1, 2,3,4);`

Comment: This is wonderful, you actually covered lot of aspects here in addition to the OP, I tried passing another value at the end of function declaration out of curiosity and got error  `Rest parameter must be last formal parameter`, that explains it. Thanks, also tried passing mixed types :)

Answer (score 1):

Because that's your first argument of your function signature

```
myConcat(', ', 'red', 'orange', 'blue');

function myConcat(separator) {...}
```

Try changing the signature as `function myConcat(separator, arg1, arg2, arg3)` and you'll see that all arguments are received as expected.

You can even write the signature as `function myConcat()`. and call the function.
Because, JS doesn't do type checking.
However, you can still check with how many arguments the function was called with `arguments.length` within the function.

For more reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp
[Function arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments)

Comment: Thank you for helping, I understood now that even if I don't declare any argument in function declaration, `arguments` object can identify the passed values. And if I am declaring, it will have the value in the order it is declared, in this case, the declared separator takes the value comma. I tried `function myConcat(separator, second)` and `console.log(second);` prints `second`.

Answer (score 1):

```
myConcat(', ', 'red', 'orange', 'blue');
```

here, first argument is `,` that is actually the value of **separator** `function myConcat(separator){...}`

And when you iterating through the arguments, loop starts from index `1`, not from `0` (Note, arguments[0] is your separator actually)

```
for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  result += arguments[i] + separator;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Sajib when i printed arguments.length i got 4, so i understood that arguments[0] was comma, but i couldn't relate how comma ( why only comma) was assigned to the separator variable .. now it's clear from all the explanations

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
 function array(separator, ...array) {
 var result = ""; // initialize the resulting string
   // iterate over the array
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   result += array[i] + separator;
     }
      return result;
  }
   alert(array( "a",/*...array*/ "b", "n", "n", "!"));
  </script>
```

Comment: OUTPUT :banana!a

Comment: here,in simple meaning a is used as seperator therefore after every array element a is printed.
I will suggest you run this code on any compiler and do multiple edits and changes then you can easily understand the code

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Update (and format) your answer and don't add comments yourself.